# How not to show the background of a parent

Tags: css, background-image

I have a `div` and it has a background image. But I finally understood that I forgot another background for the `div` that goes at the bottom. so I used the `:after` pseudo and inserted one.

The background that goes in the `:after` was supposed to be a transparent image that fades well with the background of the body. But now the background of the parent `div` is getting behind what is in the `:after` pseudo element.

Could there be any way I would make the background of the parent `div` not to show in my `:after` pseudo element?

**Edit**
here is my code

```
.foo{
    height: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background: url(i/myimage.png) no-repeat;
}
.foo:after{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: url(i/pseudo-elem-bg.png) no-repeat;
    content: ' ';
    height: 20px; /*takes the bottom padding
}
```

Comment: Please post your problem code.

Answer (score 0):

The [`::after` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3aafter) adds an element which is the last child of the parent selector, not a sibling (hence, *an element **after** the selected one*), so it is just natural that the background of the parent shows up if the child background is `transparent`.

You might need to use another solution than the pseudo-element, such as a real element perhaps. Seeing the current code you have might help finding the best solution for your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a pseudoelement just to add another background, you could set multiple backgrounds instead, and they will shown in the order you have set it.

Something like:

```css
div {
  background: url(bg.png),
              url(otherbg.png);
  background-position: center top,
                       center bottom;
}
```

You could use other background properties and sort them in the same way.